# is "Simple Javascript Inheritance" by John Resig still ok?

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I've found http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ and it's exactly what I'm searching for but 'm wondering if it still works and if can cause any issue.

Comment: I don't know. Resig's one of the big hitters of Javascript. I'd guess he wouldn't necessarily leave something up if it were wrong, but an approach isn't perfect for every situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many modern libraries use classical inheritance now. Its core method is the following (JavaScript Patterns by Stoyan Stefanov, page 127):

```
function inherit(C, P) { 
    var F = function () {}; 
    F.prototype = P.prototype; 
    C.prototype = new F(); 
    C.uber = P.prototype; 
    C.prototype.constructor = C; 
}
```

Example of projects where it's used are:

- [Google Closure](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/object/object.js#501)
- [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/oop_js_oop.js.html#l156)
- [ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Class.html#Ext-Class-cfg-extend)

Comment: I don't understand the last 2 lines... personally I like the possibility to use Base.extend({}).

What are the advantages of this method?

Comment: The two last lines save link to parent constructor and restore link to constructor (otherwise it would be equal to F). The biggest advantage for me personally is that this is a pure JS without much of new syntactic sugar introduced.

Comment: A nice extension to this answer would show how to you deal with constructors. Specifically, how you call a parent constructor from within a subclass.