# Setting C.prototype.constructor = C leads to StackOverflow

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I have been learning about js inheritance and as a study project, I'm creating my own implementation of inheritance a base class `extend` method to create new classes.  I use `C.prototype.constructor = C` as [Stoyan Sefanov says to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072551/794234), however that leads to a stack overflow when I try to call the base class constructor.

The problem is that the second level of inheritance keeps on calling it's own constructor!  If I remove that line, my inheritance seems to work fine.

[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7CM6j/).

Here is my implementation of the base class code.

```
(function(TestFramework, undefined) {
    TestFramework.Class = function() {};

    TestFramework.Class.extend = function(ctor) {
        var base = this;
        var derived = ctor;

        //Duplicate static property access to derived
        for (var property in base) {
            if (base.hasOwnProperty(property)) derived[property] = base[property];
        }

        //Create lightweight intermediate constructor to avoid calling the base constructor
        function lightweightCtor() { this.constructor = derived; };

        //Setup prototype chain
        lightweightCtor.prototype = base.prototype;
        derived.prototype = new lightweightCtor();
        derived.prototype._MyBase = lightweightCtor.prototype;
        derived.prototype._MyBaseCtor = function() {
            base.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        //Return derived class
        return derived;
    };

    TestFramework.Class.prototype.ClassName = "TestFramework.Class";
})(window.TestFramework);
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a bit of time looking at the fiddle.  I'm not entirely certain what you intend the code to do, but on line 23, you have:

```
base.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
```

which calls line 35..

```
this._MyBaseCtor();
```

.. which calls line 23, which calls line 35, etc.

Two suggestions (forgive me if you are well aware).  Use the debugger statement when debugging - **indispensable**.  And consider a library like Underscore.js if you want to use proven inheritance in a production environment.

Comment: I saw the endless loop between 23/35.  My expectation is when I call `new Student()`, it will first call the student ctor (line 45), then the person ctor (line 35), then the class ctor (line 4).  That's what `base.prototype.constructor` is supposed to refer to.

Comment: The value for base (line 7) is established during the call from line 59.  So, base.prototype.constructor.apply (line 23) returns to line 35.

Comment: Shouldn't `this` on line 7 refer to whichever object in the inheritance chain `extend` was called on?  I just verified w/ my Chrome debugger that `this` refers to the object which `extend` is called on, not always the same base.

Comment: No; see any of the plethora of discussions on JS scope. To be successful here, you will need to understand scope well.

Comment: I thought I understood scope.  Could you point me to an explanation of why the scope is not working the way I expect in this case?

Comment: Google topics like "javascript function invocation" and "Javascript this" - there are tons of good resources.  http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/ http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

Comment: Got it!  The error has nothing to do w/ `this` or scope.  It's on line 16 when I set the `lightweightCtor` constructor to `derived`!  That creates the loop.  I'm not sure why I need that line, but every implementation of JS inheritance I have read has it.  I will update the Q

Comment: Great!  Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand the problem, the solution was pretty easy.  I just had to store a reference to the original ctor before overwriting it and call that from within `_MyBaseCtor`.  Here's [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CM6j/2/).

First, take out the constructor override inside of the lightweightCtor definition.

```
//Create lightweight intermediate constructor to avoid calling the base constructor
function lightweightCtor() {};
```

Then, add a new section to configure the constructor.  Notice the check if `base.__BaseCtor` is configured and using the default `base.prototype.constructor` if it's not.

```
//Setup constructor references
derived.__BaseCtor = base.__BaseCtor || base.prototype.constructor;
derived.prototype.constructor = derived;
derived.prototype._MyBaseCtor = function() {
    derived.__BaseCtor.apply(this, arguments);
};
```